# Fading effect on horizontal recylerview like google play store?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

[image: gif of play store recylerview]

I've searched a lot but couldn't find any tutorials. I have already set up my recyclerview and i just need to implement the fading effect. So please help. Thanks in advance!
The one with developer info on it.

Answer (score 0):

> how to implement the fading effect

Setup your views in the following structure

```
<Framelayout>
  <Custom header, width 100dp/>
  <RecyclerView/>
</Framelayout>
```

Then add a 100dp `Custom space decoration` to the first item of the `RecyclerView`. 
Add a scroll listener to the `RecyclerView` and apply fade animation to the `CustomView` based on the scroll position of the `RecyclerView`.

Comment: Can you help me out with the listener? I tried onScrollListener() and all. The problem is it only triggers during changes in state and it doesn't track the scroll, so I won't have any offset to work with.